# Calculating factorials modulo a prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've been doing a programming (coding) exercise, where I'm implementing a method to calculate the remainder of $\frac{a!}{b!}$ divided by a prime number $p$. $a$ and $b$ are any integers between 1 and 1000 inclusive, while $p$ is the prime number $10^9+7$.

Since $a!$ and $b!$ can get very big, it's not possible to calculate these directly in an efficient way. Instead. The idea is to use Fermat's last theorem to simplify as follows:

If $b!$ is not a multiple of $p$, then by Fermat's Little Theorem:

$(b!)^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$

Now divide each side by $b!$ which yields

$(b!)^{p-2} \equiv \frac{1}{b!} \mod p$

Now the original problems becomes (after substitution of $\frac{1}{b!} \mod p$):

$\frac{a!}{b!} \mod p \equiv a! \times (b!)^{p-2} \mod p$

The expression $a! \times (b!)^{p-2} \mod p$ can be fairly easily implemented given specific integers $a$, $b$, and $p$ by repeatedly applying $x \times y \mod p \equiv (x \mod p)(y \mod p) \mod p$ and  modular exponentiation algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

I have two problems with the math behind this solution. Can someone help me understand two things?

1) How is it valid that $\frac{a!}{b!}$ and then dividing it by $p$ to get its remainder is equivalent to the expression $\frac{a!}{b!} \mod p$ ? Best I can tell, modular division states that

Calculating $\frac{a!}{b!} \mod p$ means finding an integer $c$ such as $b! \times c \equiv a! \mod p$. Is it necessarily true so long as $\frac{a!}{b!}$ is an integer, then the reminder of $\frac{a!}{b!}$ when divided by $p$ is the same as finding the integer $c$? It feels like there a bit of abuse of notation here that is kind of magical.

2) Fermat's Little Theorem is only valid if $b!$ is not a multiple of $p$. When is this true? Is the true that for every integer $b$ and every prime number $p$, $b!$ is guaranteed not to be a multiple of $p$?

Comment: No needto divide at all as $\frac {a!}{b!}=\prod_{k=b+1}^ak$

Comment: Is $\,a!/b!\,$ known to be an *integer* in *every* case you consider?

Answer (score 1):

For a < b, a!/b! is not an integer.  Question aborts.
For a = b, a!/b! = 1.  The remainder is 1.
For b < a, a!/b! = (b + 1)(b + 2)...a.
If p < a - b, the remainder is 0.
Otherwise use xy mod p = (x mod p)(x mod p) mod p
multiple times.